# ng pattern for allowing only '-' in input text box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, ng-pattern

Is there any pattern that will allow only '-' in the input text box and deny entering other special characters like @, #, $ etc.I tried with the pattern `ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/"` which will deny all special characters from being entered in the field.

```
   <form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/" ng-model="name" name="name">
    </form>
  <span class="error pop_up"  ng-show="myForm.name.$error.pattern">Special Characters are not allowed</span>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the hyphen at the end of your character class. When it is the last character it is assumed as a literal hyphen. For example: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$/`

```
<form name="myForm">
   <input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$/" ng-model="name" name="name">
</form>
<span class="error pop_up"  ng-show="myForm.name.$error.pattern">Special Characters are not allowed</span>
```